Bluetooth problems with Broadcom BCM43142A0
I can't turn my bluetooth on or off. My board is Bluetooth Broadcom BCM43142A0.
Supposedly the problem is the firmware that can't find it, but I don't know how to install it. Can someone help me? Thanks

Please edit to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'

I guess the quick way is to wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/releases/download/v12.0.1.1105_p4/broadcom-bt-firmware-12.0.1.1105.deb && sudo dpkg -i broadcom-bt-firmware-12.0.1.1105.deb then reboot

which version of ubuntu?
